# error: type may not reference itself as a requirement associatedtype Suffix: SuffixableContainer where Suffix.Item == Item

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols

Above error come error comes in apple documentation code when i run on playground xcode 9.2 https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html

Section: Using Type Annotations to Constrain an Associated Type

```
protocol Container {
    associatedtype Item: Equatable
    mutating func append(_ item: Item)
    var count: Int { get }
    subscript(i: Int) -> Item { get }
}
protocol SuffixableContainer: Container {
    associatedtype Suffix: SuffixableContainer where Suffix.Item == Item
    func suffix(_ size: Int) -> Suffix
}
```

Their explanation: In this protocol, Suffix is an associated type, like the Item type in the Container example above. Suffix has two constraints: It must conform to the SuffixableContainer protocol (the protocol currently being defined), and its Item type must be the same as the container’s Item type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protocol SuffixableContainer: Container {
    associatedtype Suffix: SuffixableContainer
    // ...
}
```

uses a “recursive constraint” on the associated type: The associated
type `Suffix` is constrained to the enclosing protocol `SuffixableContainer`.

Recursive constraints on associated types were were implemented in Swift 4.1, i.e. that code requires Xcode 9.3 (currently in beta).

From the [Swift CHANGELOG](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md):

> **Swift 4.1**
>
> ...
>
> [SE-0157](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0157-recursive-protocol-constraints.md) is implemented. Associated types can now declare "recursive" constraints, which require that the associated type conform to the enclosing protocol.